# Store MySQL connection data in a secure way

Tags: php, mysql, security, web

Hello fellow web developers

I am developing website with PHP and MySQL and I need a secure way to store the MySQL connection data (i.e. host, username and password) in a secure way.

I have found many answers to this question, and the best one I found is to store them in the `php.ini` file. I also realized that the key of securing such data is to store them outside of your home directory (like htdocs if you are working with `xampp` or `public_html` if you are hosting your website somewhere).

I'm storing them now in the `php.ini` file, but I won't have access to it once I upload my website.

what should I do?

Comment: You already answered your own question.

Comment: If you don't have access to something other than your public directory on the server, there's no way around storing the credentials in there, sorry.

Comment: Well yeah, but I won't have access to any file or folder outside my domain folder

Comment: For more secure access make sure that you mysql port listens to only few needed IPs and can take a step ahead with mysql-ssl connections too

Comment: so I have to accept the fact that my website is vulnerable

Comment: Ashish, I want to secure the db user credentials I'm retrieving all website data with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to put the credentials in php.ini. They're no more safe there than any other file outside your HTTP document location(s).

It's sufficient to store the connection parameters in any PHP file *outside* any directory that your HTTP requests can reach directly.  I.e. don't put it in `DocumentRoot` or in any other `Location` that your HTTP server can reach.

And make sure your server itself doesn't get compromised. If someone can hack in and get direct access to files or processes on your HTTP server, the database credentials are not your greatest worry.

If you have no access to any folder outside your domain folder, can you at least set up a `.htaccess` file to `deny from all` so that no HTTP request can have direct access to the file (or directory) where you store private data? Of course PHP code can still read such files with `include` or `require`.

Comment: I Agree that if you let only your localhost to hit the mysql port you are safe there .. probably can achieve this via iptables or my.cnf

Comment: OK, my host file system is as following: mywebsite.com/html_public/... so i can create a config file under mywebsite.com, that won't be accessible through http requests

Comment: Spot on. The only way files outside of your html_public folder can be found (now) is for your hosting to be hacked or your webserver to serve it up (which is VERY unlikely!) AND if the file has no HTML the page won't display anything in the browser If it were ever served. Trust your hosting.

Comment: @BigChris that's what I'm counting on

Comment: @BigChris, please post your own answer instead of deleting parts of mine. And your comment about files not displaying if they have no HTML is actually wrong. Text files, XML files, even PHP code that has no Apache handler, etc. can display in browsers just fine.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - I didn't delete any of your answer. I added to it to help improve it. Why duplicate an answer if you can improve an existing one that someone has put up. I am aware that if a PHP handler doesn't exist that it can display in browser but almost every hosting company configures their servers to have the right handlers for such files as .php - unless something goes wrong or the user can change configuration.

Comment: I also believe my addition was useful because most people simply use the details they're given, not realising what that account can actually do and the consequences if the details were ever compromised.